# Dropdown Menu Hover doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Dropdown menu hover is actually working but shows a different menu list element when I start pointing the mouse. For example, I was trying to choose a 'Shop' menu, when it hovers its shows an 'About' menu instead of hovering a list from the 'Shop' menu.

Also hover elements not displaying property... Could you guys help me?

here's are the codes:

```js
 var ul = document.getElementById('navClass');
window.onscroll = () => {
    if(window.scrollY < 10){
        ul.style.marginTop = '70px'
        ul.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        ul.style.boxShadow = "none";

    } 
    else{
      ul.style.marginTop = '0px'
      ul.style.backgroundColor = "#111";
      ul.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 20px black";
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  #navClass {
    color: white;
    padding: 3rem 0rem 1rem 0rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
    margin-top: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-duration: 150ms;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  #navClass ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.7vw; 
    margin-left: 150px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    

  }
  #navClass li {
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.7vw; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition:.5s;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index: 500;
  }

  #navClass a{text-decoration:none;
    color: white;

  }

  #navClass ul li:hover{
      background:orange;
      border-radius: 5px 5px;
  }

  ul.sub-menu{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: orange;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-top:-5px;
    left:200px;
    width:auto;
    padding-left:0px; 
    opacity:0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: space-between;
   
}

ul.sub-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:0px; 
}

ul.sub-menu li a:hover{
  background-color: orangered;
}


#navClass li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:100;
    opacity:1;
}

/*'nav img' is a company Logo image*/
  nav img {
    height: 5rem;
    left:-15px;
    position:relative;
    top: -60px;
    
  }


.fa-bag-shopping{
    position:relative;
    left:-1%;
    top:-80px;
    font-size:2vw;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;

}

.login{
    position:relative;
    left: 4%;
    top:-80px;
    font-size: 1vw;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    padding-right:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
   
}

.fa-magnifying-glass{
    left: 280px;
    position:relative;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    font-size:1.5em;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navClass">
    <img src="Images/AnaheraLogo.png" alt="Anahera Logo" />
    <ul>
      <li ><a href = "Anahera_Homepage.html">Home</a></li>|
      <li><a href = "#">Shop<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class ="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Most Popular</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Flowers</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Plants</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Gifts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>|
      <li><a href = "#">Occasions<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
      <ul class ="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="Anahera_Page2.html">Most Popular</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Valentines</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Wedding</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Birthday</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Anniversary</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>|
      <li><a href = "#">About<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
      <ul class ="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fresh Flowers Guaranteed</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>|
      <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
    <a class ="login" style="color:white;" href ="#"> Join/Login</a>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping" style = color:white; href ="#"></i>
  </nav>
```

I tried to fix it for many hours but it doesn't seem to work and I'm almost out of my mind... Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with your CSS you are using the position fixed property for your submenu class that is opening your all submenus at a fixed position. I have edited the CSS please have a look and let me know if it solves the issue.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('navClass');
window.onscroll = () => {
    if(window.scrollY < 10){
        ul.style.marginTop = '70px'
        ul.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        ul.style.boxShadow = "none";

    } 
    else{
      ul.style.marginTop = '0px'
      ul.style.backgroundColor = "#111";
      ul.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 20px black";
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  #navClass {
    color: white;
    padding: 3rem 0rem 1rem 0rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
    margin-top: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-duration: 150ms;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  #navClass > ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.7vw; 
    margin-left: 150px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    

  }
  #navClass li {
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.7vw; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition:.5s;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index: 500;
  }

  #navClass a{text-decoration:none;
    color: white;

  }

  #navClass ul li:hover{
      background:orange;
      border-radius: 5px 5px;
  }


ul.sub-menu li a:hover{
  background-color: orangered;
}

/*'nav img' is a company Logo image*/
  nav img {
    height: 5rem;
    left:-15px;
    position:relative;
    top: -60px;
    
  }


.fa-bag-shopping{
    position:relative;
    left:-1%;
    top:-80px;
    font-size:2vw;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;

}

.login{
    position:relative;
    left: 4%;
    top:-80px;
    font-size: 1vw;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    padding-right:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
   
}

.fa-magnifying-glass{
    left: 280px;
    position:relative;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    font-size:1.5em;
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
#navClass ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding-left:0px;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
#navClass ul li:hover > ul {
      display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navClass">
    <img src="Images/AnaheraLogo.png" alt="Anahera Logo" />
    <ul>
      <li ><a href = "Anahera_Homepage.html">Home</a></li>|
      <li><a href = "#">Shop<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <ul class ="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Most Popular</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Flowers</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Plants</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Gifts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>|
      <li><a href = "#">Occasions<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
      <ul class ="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="Anahera_Page2.html">Most Popular</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Valentines</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Wedding</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Birthday</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Anniversary</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>|
      <li><a href = "#">About<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
      <ul class ="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fresh Flowers Guaranteed</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>|
      <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
    <a class ="login" style="color:white;" href ="#"> Join/Login</a>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping" style = color:white; href ="#"></i>
  </nav>
```

Comment: yeah it's working for me. as a beginner, I learn something new about CSS tricks from your idea so thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sounds Good...!